# Closed form for $0^n0!+1^n1!+\cdots+k^nk!$

Tags: summation, factorial, closed-form

We have
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}k^nk!$$
Is there a nice closed form for this sum?

Comment: By expressing $k^n$ as a linear combinations of $1$ and $\{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+i)\}_{i=1}^n$ you can write it in terms of $a_n \equiv \sum_{k=0}^n k!$. E.g. $k^2 = (k+1)(k+2) - 3(k+1) + 1$ so the sum for $n=2$ can be written $a_{n+2} - 3a_{n+1} + a_n$

Comment: @Winther, thank you for comment! Only recurrence, nothing else?

Comment: That's the best we can do (I think). It's only for $n=1$ we have a closed form (due to telescoping). Also note that even the sums's $a_n$ don't really have an elementary closed form: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html

Comment: @Winther, thank you twice!

Comment: $\sum _{k=0}^m k^n k!=\int_0^{\infty } \left(-e^{-x} x^{1+m} \Phi (x,-n,1+m)+e^{-x} \text{Li}_{-n}(x)\right) \, dx$ where: $\Phi$ is LerchPhi and $Li$  is PolyLog.